# Warning saying `Id` exist and should be destroyed

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Most of the time i see the following Warning, when i click on the same button for more than once (when calling the same function twice or more)

```
[WARN] [WARN][Ext.Component#constructor] Registering a component with a id (`name`) which has already been used. Please ensure the existing component has been destroyed (`Ext.Component#destroy()`.
```

How should i `destroy` it as the Warning suggest ? or how should i fix this ?

**UPDATE**

```
function onPersonFound(imageData) {
           var image = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
                                 src: "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData,
                                 id: 'logo',
                                 width: 372,
                                 height: 140
                                 });
```

Answer (score 5):

> [WARN][Ext.Component#constructor] Registering a component with a id
>   (`name`) which has already been used. Please ensure the existing
>   component has been destroyed (`Ext.Component#destroy()`.

Warning states that you are creating and destroying the component with `id:name` too fast. So, I would suggest you to remove the hard-coded `id` property on that component and instead use `itemId`.

Why to use `itemId` over `id`?

> An itemId can be used as an alternative way to get a reference to a
>   component when no object reference is available. Instead of using an
>   id with Ext.getCmp, use itemId with Ext.Container.getComponent which
>   will retrieve itemId's or id's. **Since itemId's are an index to the
>   container's internal MixedCollection, the itemId is scoped locally to
>   the container - avoiding potential conflicts with Ext.ComponentManager
>   which requires a unique id.**

Comment: When i add `itemId ` instead of `id` i am unable to navigate from view to view.

Answer (score 0):

According to your controller function, this is because at the first time you clicked on your button, Sencha Touch creates an `Ext.Image` with id `logo`. At the second time, another image with id `logo` is created, so there are 2 components with the same `id`. It leads to wrong query results if they base on `id` property.

Just simply be more "specific" in your `id` config when you create any components to ensure there're no components with same `id` at anytime. For example:

```
function onPersonFound(imageData) {
           var image = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
                                 src: "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData,
                                 id: 'logo' + person_id,
                                 width: 372,
                                 height: 140
                                 });
```

Note: I wrote`person_id` to represent an **unique** field of your instance that ensures there're no images with same `id`. Wish it helps you.