# Selectfield events are lost when changing views

Tags: touch, extjs, onchange, event-listener

I have a strange problem with all my selectfields. When I enter a view for the first time containing a selectfield with a change event listener defined in the controller, it works fine. I can do a select and the event will fire. But when I enter an other view and pop that view so I return in the view with the selectfield, the change event does not fire anymore. Also the selected value is gone. I've tried to add the listeners to the config in the view, but that is not working at all?

This is more ore less an example of what I'm doing.

Controller:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Search', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs:{
            distanceSelect:'#distanceSelect',
        },
        control:{
            distanceSelect:{
                change:'filterSearchList',
            },
        }
    },

    filterSearchList:function(){
        alert('42!!');
    }
});
```

View:

```
Ext.define('Abedrijven.view.search.Search_main', {
    extend:'Abedrijven.view.Screen',
    alias:'widget.search_main',
    requires:[
        'Ext.field.Select',
    ],

    config:{
        items:[{
           xtype: 'selectfield',
           id: 'distanceSelect',
           name:'distance',
           options: [{
               text: '- All -',
               value: '0'
           }, {
               text: '5 Km.',
               value: '5'
           }, {
               text: '10 Km.',
               value: '10'
           }
        }]
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

I have this in my app.js. I call these when I want to change the views.

```
launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    // Initialize the main view
    var view = Ext.create('Abedrijven.view.Main');
    Ext.Viewport.add(view);

    Abedrijven.app.view = view;

    Abedrijven.app.pushView = function(xtype,data){
        Abedrijven.app.view.push({xtype:xtype,data:data});
    }

    Abedrijven.app.popView = function(){
        Abedrijven.app.view.pop();
    },

    Abedrijven.app.goHome = function(){
        Abedrijven.app.view.reset();
    }

    Abedrijven.app.view.add({xtype:'home_main'});
},
```

My main view:

```
Ext.define("Abedrijven.view.Main", {

extend:'Ext.NavigationView',
requires:[
    'Ext.Toolbar',
    'Ext.tab.Panel',
    'Ext.TitleBar',
],
alias:'widget.main',
id:'mainview',

config:{
    cls:['mainview'],
    fullscreen: true,
    ui:'dark',
    items:[
```

The first time it all works, change to other view, and than change back to this view and the change event will not fire. I'm using ST 2.0.1.1 GPL. Tested on iOS and browser.

Any help would be great!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have an error message in the console ? It might be that the second time the view containing your selectfield appears it recreates the selectfield with the same ID as the previous one. In this case there would be an ID conflict. Could you add the code relevant to the change of view ?

Comment: Yes indeed, not an error but a warning. [WARN][Ext.Component#constructor] Registering a component with a id (`distanceSelect`) which has already been used. Please ensure the existing component has been destroyed (`Ext.Component#destroy()`. But when must I destroy the field? Or is there a better way to fix this?

Comment: Again, could you post the code you're using to change views ? There must be something wrong in it.

Comment: I've edited my question. Added launch from my app.js. I call these when I want to change the views.

Comment: I have the same problem with buttons and other objects, but they don't lose there event handlers when parsed again. Why didn't I notice these warnings before... Thanks for any input you can give me :)

Comment: So you're working in a navigation.view right ? Did you set its autoDestroy config to false ?

Comment: Yes a navigation view, and no I didn't set its autoDestroy. I've added my main view code.

Comment: Thanks for your help! A google search on sencha touch id conflicts helped me to find a solution. You are my hero for today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem because I was using views defined and instantiated at runtime. First time was fine, second one the controller was loosing the listeners.

I solved the problem simply using dom subqueries.

config: {
   refs: {
      RecordTypeSelectField  : '**NewRecordPanel** #recordTypeSelectField'

Essentially you simply add the parent container to the query key. That's all!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the bug. I was using **id**'s, but **itemId** is better. [Here the answer that helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10624087/536590) figuring this out.

```
id:'myid'
```

replaced to

```
itemId:'myid'
```

Needed to change some code to get the right elements again, but now it works